# The addEventListener does not work in external Javascript file, but does when placed directly on ASP page. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

Bear with me as I try and explain this. I have this javascript file with multiple functions on it. Nothing fancy, just a few that change text box colors and one that I want to run a regex check on.

Problem: I have a text box that I want to check for numbers and letters only. Here is the simple function I use to do so --

/* This sits in an external JS file */

```
function checkTextBox() 
{
    var userInfo = document.document.getElementById('TextBox1');
    var pattern = new RegExp(/[~`!#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\\';,/{}|\\":<>\?]/); 
    //unacceptable chars
    if (pattern.test(userInfo)) {
        alert("Please only use standard alphanumerics");
        return false;`enter code here`
    }
    return true; //good user input
}

var elLicenseHolder = document.getElementById('TextBox1');
elLicenseHolder.addEventListener('blur', checkTextBox, false);
```

fairly straightforward and easy. However, I get this error when running the page and after the page has loaded.

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at VM109 index.js:48"

I realize this may be happening due to the TextBox being empty however, shouldn't it still fire after I input bad data and click out of the box? Executing the blur portion of the addEventListener?

In addition, that very same function minus the addEventListener works fine when placed directly on the ASP page. Like this.

```
<p class="form_labels">Product Supported -- 
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" class="ddl_text_small"  runat="server" onblur="checkTextBox();" ></asp:TextBox>
                        </p>
                         <script>
                             function checkTextBox() {
                                 var userInfo = document.document.getElementById('TextBox1');
                                 var pattern = new RegExp(/[~`!#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\\';,/{}|\\":<>\?]/); //unacceptable chars
                                 if (pattern.test(userInfo)) {
                                     alert("Please only use standard alphanumerics");
                                     return false;
                                 }
                                 return true; //good user input
                             }
                            </script>
```

When I refresh my page and try again, this works fine.

Just so everyone knows, I have tried placing the  tag all over the page. From the head, to both before and after the text box in question, and at the bottom of the page.  I have fooled with body and window onload events. Nothing seems to work. I may have to resort to keeping the JS on the ASP page, but I would prefer it if I can have it in an external file. Any help would be awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not working because by default ASP.Net will change Id of your server control. You can disable it by setting `ClientIDMode` property to `static`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx

Also, make sure to load javascript file at the end of your html document.

Comment: Thanks Dipen for the answer. I thought I had put that info in my question, but maybe I didn't clarify it enough. I have tried loading the js file at the beginning of the page, (in the <head> section) . I've placed the script src just after the text box itself, and at the very end of the page. Near the closing </body> and </html> tags. None of which works.

Comment: @swapmeet_Lou Why don't you try to use onreadystatechange to set an initializer funtion.

Comment: @swapmeet_Lou My bad I was looking at the question from html view point and not asp.net. Hope, this should do the trick.

Comment: I've not used onreadystatechange before. Unfamiliar with some of the syntax Dipen. Do you have any examples? I found one through w3c, but unsure of the xhttp.open syntax. specifically the url param.   P.S.  I tried the ClientIDMode="Static" on the textbox itself. That didn't solve it so, onto the onreadystatechange